# How to use api ipinfodb in php

Tags: php, ip

I am trying to use the free api ipinfodb service in php code on my server.
I registered my server ip with the service and I got my API key.

If I run the service directly through my browser like this:

```
http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=<apikey>&ip=117.212.155.134
```

It works well and quickly returns a string like this:

```
OK;;117.212.155.134;IN;INDIA;MAHARASHTRA;CHIPLUN;415726;17.5333;73.5167;+05:30
```

However, when I try to run the same thing through php on my server, it clocks forever and fails with a timeout error.

This logic works on my local server, but not on my remote HostGator server.
If I replace api.infodb.com with another website address, a proper result is returned.
It's almost as if api.ipinfodb.com is blocking my hostgator server from making the call.
I did register my hostgator server ip address with api.ipinfodb.com and my api key.

What is causing the timeout error?

```
<?php
$ip = "117.212.155.134";
$lookup = sprintf('http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=<apikey>&ip=%s', $ip);
$result = trim(file_get_contents($lookup));
echo $result . "<br />\n";
```

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your php.ini? Also you may want to set headers like in the Example 4 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Shot in the dark, but are you sure DNS is working on your server? In other words, can you ping api.ipinfodb.com?

Comment: @oliakaoil assuming it is because when he talks about running it though a browser I'm assuming it would be the browser on the server. So it wouldn't work through the browser if it were a DNS issue.

Comment: @Pitchinnate - allow_url_fopen is enabled

Comment: Another shot in the dark... you **are** inserting your API key, right? It would be a silly mistake to leave `<apikey>` in there, but one that we've all made :-)

Comment: Also you might want to `urlencode` the api key if it has anything other than letters and numbers.

Comment: @Kryten.. I'm capable of making that mistake, but sadly I didn't this time.  So, still no joy.

Comment: @Pitchinnate, the apikey is only letters and numbers. :(

Comment: UPDATE: the code works on my local machine WAMP server... so the problem may be with my remote server which is provided by hostgator.  However, when I provide a different website address (instead of api.ipinfodb.com) I do get back results in a timely manner.

Comment: Wait so is the browser you are talking about on the server or your local machine? Is it a windows or linux server? If linux do you have ssh access.

Comment: @pitchinnate.. the browser is local... I don't have gui access to my hostgator server.

Comment: Do you have ssh access?

Comment: yes, I have ssh access

Comment: I would try to see if you can do a `wget` or as @oliakaoil said do a ping from ssh.

Comment: I tried ping, but apparently hostgator won't let me do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57541/discussion-between-panofish-and-pitchinnate).

Comment: I've been needing this services in some projects lately. I've created a simple PHP helper/wrapper available at https://github.com/DaanDeSmedt/IPInfoDB-PHP-Wrapper. In case this fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the exact output as you do when using the browser.

```
$arr_location=file_get_contents('http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=**YOURKEY**&ip='.**$THE_IP_TO_LOOKUP**);

print_r($arr_location);
```