# ipinfodb returning empty array to hostgator server

Tags: php, ip

I've installed an ipinfodb library in my CodeIgniter application to get geolocation data from user ips. I'm pretty sure it's configured correctly since it works on my local xampp server.

The issue is that on my hostgator vps, there is no response, and all I end up with is an empty array.

Here is the code:

```
$ip = $this->input->ip_address();

$config = $this->config->config['geolocation'];

$this->geolocation->initialize($config);
$this->geolocation->set_ip_address($ip);

$location_arr = $this->geolocation->get_country();
$country = $location_arr["countryCode"];
```

Here is a var_dump of location_arr:

```
array(0) { }
```

var_dump of $ip:

```
string(14) "85.166.230.252"
```

var_dump of $config (with API key censored):

```
array(4) { ["api"]=> string(25) "https://api.ipinfodb.com/" ["api_version"]=> string(2) "v3" ["api_key"]=> string(64) "the-api-key" ["format"]=> string(0) "" }
```

allow_url_fopen is set to On through cPanel's php.ini tool. The API key is set. The server ip is set in the ipinfodb account.

I see that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807039/how-to-use-api-ipinfodb-in-php) has been asked before in 2014 by someone with the same problem, but it doesn't seem to be resolved.

Comment: in your current code just after starting `<?php` tag add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and then run and check any error is showing or not? also can you please tell the output of `var_dump($ip);` and `var_dump($config);`?

Comment: I added the other var_dumps to the post now. I am getting a php notice with error_reporting on, saying "Undefined index: countryCode", but that's because the array is empty, right?